# How to use Exception stategy & RouteNotFoundStrategy

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I would like to undertsand why if i set $response->statusCode(404); in my onBootstrap() module method, i have no dispach.error or render.error event created.

I have the render of the 404 page but just because statusCode has set... No error to grab for reporting ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the response object to short-circuit the rest of the dispatch process. Returning $response after you modify it should result in the 404 page being shown.

Comment: I'm not sure than return response is great...
[look this](http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Throw-exception-and-have-a-Status-404-Not-Found-response-td4655198.html)

Comment: I can only presume that is referenced to the controller, hence the reference to getResponse. Allowing the dispatch process to continue will potentially overwrite the 404 status you set with 200 if the dispatch process deems the status should be OK.